# Trac - suggested permission levels for developers & managers

Tags: permissions, trac

I'm a fan of [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/), and of course when I'm just using it for my own, lone, projects I can just give myself full admin rights.

When there are other developers involved, or a not-very-technical manager (or, for that matter someone that is a designer rather than hard-code developer), that needs to be able to keep up with what is happening - and do things like add/update tickets, but not potentially break anything, then the fine-grained nature of the permissions gets to be a little more complicated as to what is required for someone.

What permissions do you use for those groups of people (and other similar ones)?

Answer (score 3):

I generally avoid giving the `*_ADMIN` perms to users if I can avoid it.  Trac 0.11 makes that a little easier by adding `TICKET_EDIT_DESCRIPTION`.

Depending on the setup and the culture, I'll grant the `*_VIEW` permissions to `authenticated` (everyone who has logged in) or in lax setups, `anonymous` (everyone, even not logged in).

I will generally create a `developer` group, grant the various permissions to that group.  Then you just add people to the group (or add the group as a permission to the user, same thing).  Do the same for `designer`, `manager`, `tester`, etc.

A manager would want the various `ROADMAP_*` and `MILESTONE_*` permissions.  I'd be cautious about `REPORT_ADMIN` unless the manager actually knows SQL.  My boss is generally happy to give me an example spreadsheet of the report he wants and I'll whip up a report for him.  Be sure to point out to them that if they setup a custom query that does what they want, they can bookmark it -- everything is in the URL -- so they can go back to exactly that same query with current data using that bookmark.

You'd probably want to let `authenticated` file and append to tickets--doesn't usually who notices a bug, you still want to know about it.  If you lock down the workflow permissions enough, you may be able to give out `TICKET_MODIFY` to more people as well, though that route will be a bit more work.

Those you have some trust in can probably be granted `TICKET_EDIT_DESCRIPTION` so they can fix up their bug report formatting when they forgot to to start with.

If you have a lead developer, that individual user should probably have `TICKET_ADMIN` to deal with adding versions and such.

Comment: +1 for your third paragraph on groups -- I do the same thing but didn't think to mention it.

Answer (score 2):

I typically turn on all the `VIEW`s, plus `WIKI_CREATE`, `WIKI_MODIFY`, `TICKET_CREATE` (or `TICKET_CREATE_SIMPLE` if using the Simple Ticket plugin) and `TICKET_APPEND`.

For users I trust to have a little more power, I'll also turn on `TICKET_MODIFY`.

For a non-technical manager, I'll also turn on `MILESTONE_ADMIN`.  For a technical manager, I'm likely to jump to `TRAC_ADMIN` -- but if that's too far, at least add `REPORT_ADMIN`.

Typically, I'll go ahead and give the developers `TRAC_ADMIN`... but if you don't trust them that far, the above permissions through the power user level plus `TICKET_ADMIN` are probably sufficient.